# I want to access another server database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am really a beginner in PHP and Mysql. I made a database on **static IP 192.168.1.211** which is based on **CentOS(only Command prompt)** and on this IP there is no other software like easyPHP, and I am working on **static IP 192.168.1.20** based on **Windows 7**. I also installed **easyPHP** and **Dreamweaver**... using Dreamweaver I made one .php file and I tried to use the database which is on **192.168.1.20**..

*using below code*

```
<?php
    $server2 = '192.168.1.211';
    $con = mysqli_connect(server2,'root','password','vvani');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

but I get an error as shown below

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant server2 - assumed 'server2' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\test\welcome.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\test\welcome.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\test\welcome.php on line 4
Failed to connect to MySQL: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

How can I access the database on 192.168.1.211 from 192.168.1.20 in PHP code?

I also tried hard to find a solution from Google, but I am not getting a perfect solution.

Comment: You are missing the $ sign

Comment: `Use of undefined constant server2` .Error reading skill is as important as knowing the language syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read errors and correct it..

```
<?php
$server2 = '192.168.1.211';
$con = mysqli_connect($server2,'root','password','vvani'); // here, $server2 is variable, not constant
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: This is a reminder that every single character in your program is important. There is no "close enough" in programming.

Comment: Thanks @Elon Than, I used `$server2` in stand of only `server2` but problem not solved, I get a warning `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '192.168.1.20' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\test\welcome.php on line 4`
**This error is remote access error and I solved this error using below code**
`mysql> GRANT ALL ON fooDatabase.* TO fooUser@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';`
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change `server2` to `$server2`.  If that still doesn't work then it's possible the other server does not allow requests in such a way so you will have to update the MySQL settings on that server to allow external access to the port (or otherwise forward it).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Elon Than** and **Explosion Pills**,

I changed `server2` to `$server2`, but I get new warning

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '192.168.1.20' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\test\welcome.php on line 4
```

And I research on it and I try to give remotely access to database on another server.

Follow some few steps and solved problem.

```
# mysql -u root -p
mysql> GRANT ALL ON Database.* TO <un>@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Thanks again.